Am trying to install react-native-screen so i can run the navigations but am getting an error
npm start -- --reset-cache

isafari@0.0.1 start
react-native start --reset-cache

info Welcome to React Native v0.75
info Starting dev server on port 8081...
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
              ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
             ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
             ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
              ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒

warning: the transform cache was reset.
Welcome to Metro v0.80.12
Fast - Scalable - Integrated
info Dev server ready
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android
d - open Dev Menu
r - reload app
info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...

Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:processResources NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:classes UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:shared:jar UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:settings-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
Task :gradle-plugin:react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :app:generateAutolinkingPackageList
Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
Task :app:preBuild
Task :app:preDebugBuild
Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugResources
Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
Task :react-native-bootsplash:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-screens:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-svg:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-vector-icons:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :app:mergeDebugStartupProfile UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-bootsplash:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-community_masked-view:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :react-native-safe-area-context:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
Task :app:processDebugResources
Task :react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
168 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 152 up-to-date
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.


[CXX1210] /home/leston/ISafari/app/isafari/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 17s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
i tried to install a older version of react-native screens
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/cli": "^14.1.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "^0.75.3",
"react-native-bootsplash": "^6.1.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
"react-native-svg": "^15.7.1",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0"
},
